# How to match with space using regex

Tags: jquery, regex

The following word can be an entry:

```
1200
90
Ashton
Created By
Johnson & Johnson
Lemon Pie
Xavier
```

I have the following `RegEx`:

```
var rexp = new RegExp('^' + val, 'i');
```

I am entering the following:

```
If I enter `12`, there is a match, `1200`.

If I enter `Lem`, there is a match, `Lemon Pie`.

If I enter `Lemon P`, there is no match.

If I enter `Johnson &`, there is no match.

If I enter `&`, there is no match.
```

How can I modify the `RegExp()` function, so it takes space into account to find a match, so:

```
If I enter `12`, there is a match, `1200`.

If I enter `Lem`, there is a match, `Lemon Pie`.

If I enter `Lemon P`, there is a match, `Lemon Pie`.

If I enter `Johnson &`, there is a match, `Johnson & Johnson`.

If I enter `&`, there is a match, `Johnson & Johnson`.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all space with `\\s`.

**E.g.**

```
var pattern = '^' + val.replace(' ', '\\s');
var rexp = new RegExp(pattern, 'i');
```

`\\s` will print as `\s`, which matches `space` in your word.

If you also want to replace multiple spaces with one space in your pattern, you can also do it like,

```
var pattern = '^' + val.replace(/\s+/, '\\s');
```

Here's your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e0gf876x/2/)

**Edit:**

`^` matches for the beginning of line. If you just want to matches the word that you enter in the input, without matching the starting letter, then you can avoid regex in the first place.

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e0gf876x/3/)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning how error prune it will be to use user data to generate a regex, eg if `val='?'` the regex will fail: `/^?/i`

Comment: @andlrc That's the matter of validity of the string passed. I believe OP is aware of it..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e0gf876x/ with my code... https://jsfiddle.net/e0gf876x/1/ with your code.

Comment: Spaces have no special meaning in regular expressions, I don't see the point of replacing them, unless the matched data does not contain spaces, which the question does not seems to point out.

Comment: What would you suggest @Aaron

Comment: @Si8 you're not matching the regex against the data, but against `$('span', this).text().split(" ").join("")` which remove spaces from it. The regex has no problem, the data you match it against has. Try using `lemonp` as input, it will match 'Lemon Pie'.

Comment: OH WOW... the existing RexExp that I had works but seeing that I am an idiot my join and split was causing the issue :/

Comment: @Si8 Please check the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e0gf876x/2/).

Comment: @Aaron I noticed that also, but first i thought it's safer to detect space with `\s` since it matches any white space including space, tab, line feed, whatsoever..

Comment: @choz If I enter `&`, nothing is displayed :/

Comment: @Si8 Because your original regex uses `^` which matches the beginning of line. You don't have any word starts with '&', do you? If you just want to match for any word, it'd be much simpler if you don't use regex at all.

Comment: `Johnson & Johnson`... I don't know. What do you recommend.

Comment: @Si8 The regex approach should also match for `Johnson & Johnson`. But if you just input `&` , it would not match because then your regex would evaluate like `/^&/i`. Check my edit part of the updated answer for non regex approach.

Comment: I like the non regex solution. I accepted and +1 your answer. Thank you.